# R messy date to convert into proper year month sequence

Tags: r, date, shiny, xlsx

I have a date column in xlsx with no sequence of dates. I would like to convert the date column so it appears in sequence starting year from `08-23` for example `4 Aug` becomes `04-08-2023`  and so on as the data added in for year 2024 onwards.

What  i have tried from source [Working with dates](https://epirhandbook.com/en/working-with-dates.html)

```
FixDate-> as.Date(xlsx_filePath$Date, origin = "4 Aug")
openxlsx::convertToDate(xlsx_filePath$Date)
```

or

```
FixDate-> as.Date(xlsx_filePath$Date,  format = "%d/%m/%Y")
openxlsx::convertToDate(xlsx_filePath$Date)
```

| Date | Firm |
| --- | --- |
| 1 Jan | firm9 |
| 8 Jan | firm10 |
| 1 Dec | firm1 |
| 8 Dec | firm2 |
| 14 Dec | firm3 |
| 4 Aug | firm4 |
| 11 Aug | firm5 |
| 25 Aug | firm6 |
| 1 Sep | firm7 |
| 8 Sep | firm8 |
| 14 Jan | firm8 |

**Expected Outcome**

| Date | Firm |
| --- | --- |
| 04-08-2023 | firm4 |
| 11-08-2023 | firm5 |
| 25-08-2023 | firm6 |
| 01-09-2023 | firm1 |
| 08-09-2023 | firm2 |
| 01-12-2023 | firm7 |
| 08-12-2023 | firm8 |
| 14-12-2023 | firm3 |
| 01-01-2024 | firm9 |
| 08-01-2024 | firm10 |
| 14-01-2024 | firm10 |

Comment: What is `FixDate -> ...` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you with your problem. It may be not the most elegant solutions but it works. I used parse_date to get the day-months to a date. This will automatically add the current year (2024) to these dates. Then I used lubridate to substract 1 year from all dates later than 4 august. And then another mutate step to get the dates to the same format as your example.

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(lubridate)
    library(parsedate)
    
    dt <- c("1 Jan", "8 Jan", "1 Dec", "8 Dec", "14 Dec", "4 Aug", "11 Aug", 
             "25 Aug", "1 Sep", "8 Sep", "14 Jan")
    firm <- c("firm9", "firm10","firm1", "firm2", "firm3", "firm4", "firm5",
              "firm6", "firm7", "firm8", "firm8")
    df <- data.frame(dt, firm)

    df %>% mutate(dates = parse_date(dt)) %>% 
           mutate(dates = case_when(
                          dates >= "2024-08-04" ~ dates - years(1),
                          TRUE ~ dates)) %>% 
           mutate(dates = format(dates, "%d-%m-%Y"))
```

```
       dt   firm      dates
1   1 Jan  firm9 01-01-2024
2   8 Jan firm10 08-01-2024
3   1 Dec  firm1 01-12-2023
4   8 Dec  firm2 08-12-2023
5  14 Dec  firm3 14-12-2023
6   4 Aug  firm4 04-08-2023
7  11 Aug  firm5 11-08-2023
8  25 Aug  firm6 25-08-2023
9   1 Sep  firm7 01-09-2023
10  8 Sep  firm8 08-09-2023
11 14 Jan  firm8 14-01-2024
```

As a sidenote: I noticed that the date - firm combinations in the start table and the expected outcome table do not match up. I used the data from the start table to generate this outcome.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the documentation for `?strptime` for the various formats that can be parsed, the two key ones here should be:

- `%d`: Day of the month as decimal number (01–31).
- `%b`: Abbreviated month name in the current locale on this platform.

After that, `lubridate` is your friend for working with dates. This should get you what you want (but will only work between Aug 2023 and Jul 2024 while being executed in the year 2024):

```r
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

x <- c("1 Jan", "4 Aug", "14 Dec")

as.Date(x, format = "%d %b") %>%
  ifelse(month(.) > 7, . - years(1), .) %>%
  as.Date(origin="1970-01-01")

#> "2024-01-01" "2023-08-04" "2023-12-14"
```

You can then reformat these dates to strings using the same formats above.